# Javascript - Problems to change the Position

Tags: javascript, css, position

I try to change the position top (CSS) value using Javascript. My element has a absolute position (`top: -300px;`). But I'm unable to set the px of my div... You can see in the code below, the version i've tried, only set to 0 work all other versions doen't affect my div-position.

```js
var value = -35;
document.getElementById("myElement").style.top = value; // Doesn't work
document.getElementById("myElement").style.top = value + 'px'; // Doesn't work
document.getElementById("myElement").style.top = 0; // Work
document.getElementById("myElement").style.top = '10px'; // Doesn't work
document.getElementById("myElement").style.top = '10'; // Doesn't work
```

So the Question is: What is wrong with my code, how can I change the value of the "top" attribute?

Comment: Can you reproduce this on `jsfiddle`

Comment: @Petschko You will need to add more info - html / css - to your question, because your posted code will work! (`.style.top = '10px'`) You can use jsfiddle or jsbin to replicate the error. Remember to only post relevant code. Also remember to post all code on SO that are posted on fiddle / jsbin

Comment: `document.getElementById("element").style.top = "100px";` works perfectly

Comment: That will, as noted by others, work perfectly well (except the last line, given that units are required); this does depend on the element being present in the DOM before you run the JavaScript, though. So I'd be interested in seeing what `console.log(document.getElementById('myElement'))` produces.

Comment: I think even setting `0` is also not working, it'll be default value.

Comment: check that.. https://jsfiddle.net/v58nwk5c/1/

Comment: This question should be closed.

Comment: something i think.. error JS before that code are called. OR... bad html!

Comment: I found it out, using your site^^ https://jsfiddle.net/nmwh4q2t/ Its because i try to use values below 0 i forget to add the "-" here in my code sorry for that...

Comment: @Tushar Sorry for double comment but "0" works... I have posted this on jsfiddle, but it tooks some time sorry for the late responses. You can see on my link that it seems that it have trouble with negative values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone will have the same problem in the furture this Answer of my own may help:
I found an workaround. Its because of the values 0 > make problems, so simply use parseInt if your value is below 0:

```
document.getElementById("myElement").style.top = parseInt(value) + 'px';
```

Thanks for all the help, this question can now be closed

Answer (score -1):

Its working perfectly.

> document.getElementById("myElement").style.top = '100px';

check the below code snippet.

```js
document.getElementById("myElement").style.top = '100px';
```

```css
button{
  
  width:100px;
  height:50px;
  padding:10px;
  background:aqua;
  border-radius:10px;
  position:absolute;
  }
```

```html
<button id="myElement">Watch me</button>
```

Comment: Didn't you read `document.getElementById("myElement").style.top = '10px'; // Doesn't work`

Comment: I mentioned here that its working.so whats the problem?

Comment: The problem is, that your answer can't solve what OP mets. As OP tried that, but no use to him.

Comment: @fuyushimoya: what is OP  means? sorry english is not my primary language ;-)

Comment: I justified here that what the op saying doesnt work,working perfectly.

Comment: @ Jean-philippe Emond: OP means original poster

Comment: @Jean-philippeEmond OP is Original Post(er) to my knowledge.